# Reading a multipage TIFF file with ImageIO fails after deployment to kubernetes

Tags: java, file, kubernetes, tiff, javax.imageio

I have a Java program that converts a multi-page file into separate image files. The code works perfectly fine when I run it locally, but when I deploy it into Kubernetes, it doesn't work at all. There are no error messages given, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
private void convertMultipageFile(File file) throws IOException {
String directoryPath = file.getParent();
log.info(directoryPath);
log.info(String.valueOf(file));
String fileType = "";
ImageIO.scanForPlugins();
ImageInputStream input = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file);
Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(input);
if (!readers.hasNext()) {
    throw new IOException("No image reader found for file: " + file);
}
ImageReader reader = readers.next();
reader.setInput(input);
int numPages = reader.getNumImages(true);
String fileName = file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().lastIndexOf('.'));
String fileExt = file.getName().substring(file.getName().lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
for (int i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
    BufferedImage image = reader.read(i);
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "tif", output);
    byte[] pageBytes = output.toByteArray();
    output.close();
    fileType = calculateOCR(pageBytes);
    log.info(fileType);
    if (fileType.contains("AnaBelge")) {
        String belgeName = fileType.split(",")[1] + "." + fileExt;
        String folderName = fileType.split(",")[1];
        directoryPath = file.getParent() + "/" + folderName;
        File directory = new File(directoryPath);
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            boolean created = directory.mkdir();
            if (created) {
                File newFile = new File(directoryPath, belgeName);
                ImageIO.write(image, fileExt, newFile);
            } else {
                log.warn("Failed to create directory.");
            }
        } }
    else {
        String newFileName = fileName + "_page" + (i + 1) + fileType + "." + fileExt;
        File newFile = new File(directoryPath, newFileName);
        ImageIO.write(image, fileExt, newFile);
    }
}
```

And this is the error I got from logs but sometimes it just doesnt give any error ->

```
java.io.IOException: No image reader found for file: /file/25-04-2023/001.tif
at com.test.ms.test.Scheduled.ScheduledOcrJob.convertMultipageFile(ScheduledOcrJob.java:161) ~[classes!/:0.0.1]
at com.test.ms.test.Scheduled.ScheduledOcrJob.convertFilesInDirectory(ScheduledOcrJob.java:130) ~[classes!/:0.0.1]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) [spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_342]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_342]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_342]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_342]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_342]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_342]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_342]
```

I'm using Kubernetes to deploy my application, and I'm not sure what the issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does `file.canRead()` return?

Comment: It returns true @VGR

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my intellij project version was jdk11 but it was 8 in dockerfile and imageio doesn't support tiff files in versions before 9 :D when I upgraded to java11 the problem resolved.